# I want to Execute stored procedure into temporary table but it gives me an error You must specify a table where to make the selection

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

**This my code where i want to insert the result of my stored procedure into #TempTable**

```
SELECT * INTO #Tempannuelguiftrecap
    EXECUTE  PSGetDetailMensuelPPM @Year,@Mois
```

Comment: A proper statement is `SELECT <fieldlist> INTO <tablename> FROM <source>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `SELECT` from a Stored Procedure. Something like `SELECT * FROM EXECUTE dbo.MySP` isn't going to work.

You can still `INSERT` the data from a Stored Procedure into a table, however, you must first define the table, and then `INSERT` the data. This is Pseudo-SQL as we have no definitions of your objects, however, this should get you on the right path:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable({Column1} {Data Type}[,
                          {Other Column(s)} {Column DataType(s)} ..... ]);

INSERT INTO #MyTempTable ({Columns List})
EXECUTE dbo.MyStoredProcedure @MyParam;
```